# Pandas drop method behaves inconsistently dropping a NaN header

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I've run into an issue trying to drop a `nan` column from a table.

Here's the example that works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 
                    columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                    index=['Foo', 'Bar'])

mapping1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'x'], ['b', 'y']], 
                        index=['A', 'B'], 
                        columns=['Test', 'Control'])

# rename the columns using the mapping file
df1.columns = mapping1.loc[df1.columns, 'Test']
```

From here we see that the `C` column in `df1` doesn't have an entry in the mapping file, and so that header is replaced with a `nan`.

```
# drop the nan column
df1.drop(np.nan, axis=1)
```

In this situation, calling `np.nan` finds the final header and drops it.

However, in the situation below, the `df.drop` does not work:

```
# set up table
sample1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=3)
sample2 = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=3)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([sample1, sample2], 
                   index=['sample1', 'sample2'], 
                   columns=range(3))
mapping2 = pd.DataFrame(['foo']*2, index=range(2), 
                        columns=['test'])

# assign columns using mapping file
df2.columns = mapping2.loc[df2.columns, 'test']

# try and drop the nan column
df2.drop(np.nan, axis=1)
```

And the `nan` column remains.

Answer (score 3):

This may be an answer (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629125/5717589):

> When index is unique, pandas use a hashtable to map key to value.
>   When index is non-unique and sorted, pandas use binary search,
>   when index is random ordered pandas need to check all the keys in the
>   index.

So, if entries are unique, `np.nan` gets hashed I think. In a non-unique cases, pandas compares values, but:

```
np.nan == np.nan
Out[1]: False
```

**Update**

I guess it's impossible to access a `NaN` column by label. But it's doable by index position. Here is a workaround for dropping columns with null labels:

```
notnull_col_idx = np.arange(len(df.columns))[~pd.isnull(df.columns)]
df = df.iloc[:, notnull_col_idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... this might be considered a bug but it seems like this problem occurs if your columns are labeled with the same label, in this case as `foo`. If I switch up the labels, the issue disappears:

```
mapping2 = pd.DataFrame(['foo','boo'], index=range(2), 
                        columns=['test'])
```

I also attempted to call the columns by their index positions and the problem still occurs:

```
# try and drop the nan column
df2.drop(df2.columns[[2]], axis=1)

Out[176]:
test    foo foo nan
sample1 4   4   4
sample2 4   0   1
```

But after altering the 2nd column label to something other than foo, the problem resolves itself. My best piece of advice is to have unique column labels.

**Additional info:**
So this also occurs when there are multiple `nan` columns as well...

Comment: There are a few ways to deal with it, like renaming the final column to a non-nan and filtering the columns based on notnull(), but using drop is the more direct, and what I wanted to investigate. Glad you also found that index position doesn't work as well