# adding values in new column based on indexes with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just getting into pandas and I am trying to add a new column to an existing dataframe.

I have two dataframes where the index of one data frame links to a column in another dataframe. Where these values are equal I need to put the value of another column in the source dataframe in a new column of the destination column.

The code section below illustrates what I mean. The commented part is what I need as an output.

I guess I need the `.loc[]` function.

Another, minor, question: is it bad practice to have a non-unique indexes?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'key':['a',  'b', 'c'], 
     'bar':[1, 2, 3]}

d2 = {'key':['a', 'a', 'b'],
      'other_data':['10', '20', '30']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = d2)
df2 = df2.set_index('key')

print df2

##    other_data  new_col
##key           
##a            10   1
##a            20   1
##b            30   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Another, minor, question: is it bad practice to have a non-unique
>   indexes?

It is not great practice, but depends on your needs and can be okay in some circumstances.

#### Issue 1: join operations

A good place to start is to think about **what makes an Index different from a standard DataFrame column**.  This engenders the question: if your Index has duplicate values, does it really need to be specified as an Index, or could it just be another column in a `RangeIndex`-ed DataFrame?  If you've ever used SQL or any other DMBS and want to mimic join operations in pandas with functions such as `.join` or `.merge`, you'll lose the functionality of a [primary key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) if you have duplicate index values.  A merge will give you what is basically a cartesian product--probably not what you're looking for.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2),
                  index=2*list('abcde'))
df2 = df.rename(columns={0: 'a', 1 : 'b'})
print(df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).head(7))
         0        1        a        b
a  0.73737  1.49073  0.73737  1.49073
a  0.73737  1.49073 -0.25562 -2.79859
a -0.25562 -2.79859  0.73737  1.49073
a -0.25562 -2.79859 -0.25562 -2.79859
b -0.93583  1.17583 -0.93583  1.17583
b -0.93583  1.17583 -1.77153 -0.69988
b -1.77153 -0.69988 -0.93583  1.17583
```

#### Issue 2: performance

Unique-valued indices make certain operations efficient, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626058/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-non-unique-indexes-in-pandas) post.

> When index is unique, pandas use a hashtable to map key to value O(1).
>   When index is non-unique and sorted, pandas use binary search O(logN),
>   when index is random ordered pandas need to check all the keys in the
>   index O(N).

#### A word on `.loc`

Using `.loc` will return all instances of the label.  This can be a blessing or a curse depending on what your objective is.  For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2),
                  index=2*list('abcde'))
print(df.loc['a'])
         0        1
a  0.73737  1.49073
a -0.25562 -2.79859
```

Answer (score 9):

Use rename `index` by `Series`:

```
df2['new'] = df2.rename(index=df.set_index('key')['bar']).index
print (df2)

    other_data  new
key                
a           10    1
a           20    1
b           30    2
```

Or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2['new'] = df2.index.to_series().map(df.set_index('key')['bar'])
print (df2)

    other_data  new
key                
a           10    1
a           20    1
b           30    2
```

If want  better performance, the best is avoid duplicates in index. Also some function like `reindex` failed in duplicates index.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `join`

```
df2.join(df.set_index('key'))

    other_data  bar
key                
a           10    1
a           20    1
b           30    2
```

---

One way to rename the column in the process

```
df2.join(df.set_index('key').bar.rename('new'))

    other_data  new
key                
a           10    1
a           20    1
b           30    2
```

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `.loc`

```
df2['new'] = df.set_index('key').loc[df2.index]
```

Output :

```
   other_data  new
key                
a           10    1
a           20    1
b           30    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `combine_first`

```
In [442]: df2.combine_first(df.set_index('key')).dropna()
Out[442]:
     bar other_data
key
a    1.0         10
a    1.0         20
b    2.0         30
```

**Or**, using `map`

```
In [461]: df2.assign(bar=df2.index.to_series().map(df.set_index('key')['bar']))
Out[461]:
    other_data  bar
key
a           10    1
a           20    1
b           30    2
```