# Inconsistency between pandas xs and loc for repeated indices

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

Why is [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) only returning a single row where multiple rows have the same [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html)?

Given the following dataframe

```
           col0      col1  col2
idx0 idx1
0    0      1.0  example1   1.0
     0      4.0  example2   8.0
     1      9.0  example3  27.0
     1     16.0  example4  64.0
1    0      0.5  example1   0.5
     0      2.0  example2   4.0
     1      4.5  example3  13.5
     1      8.0  example4  32.0
```

the [`.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) operation will select

```
In [121]: df.xs((0,1), level=[0,1])
Out[121]:
           col0      col1  col2
idx0 idx1
0    1      9.0  example3  27.0
     1     16.0  example4  64.0
```

whilst the [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) operation will select

```
In [125]: df.loc[[(0,1)]]
Out[125]:
           col0      col1  col2
idx0 idx1
0    1     16.0  example4  64.0
```

This is highlighted even further by the following

```
In [149]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 1], :]
Out[149]:
           col0      col1  col2
idx0 idx1
0    1      9.0  example3  27.0
     1     16.0  example4  64.0

In [150]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[0, 1], :]
Out[150]:
col0          16
col1    example4
col2          64
Name: (0, 1), dtype: object
```

## Set Up

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx0 = range(2)
idx1 = np.repeat(range(2), 2)

midx = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels=[idx0, idx1],
    labels=[
        np.repeat(range(len(idx0)), len(idx1)),
        np.tile(range(len(idx1)), len(idx0))
    ],
    names=['idx0', 'idx1']
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [i**2/float(j), 'example{}'.format(i), i**3/float(j)]
        for j in range(1, len(idx0) + 1)
        for i in range(1, len(idx1) + 1)
    ],
    columns=['col0', 'col1', 'col2'],
    index=midx
)
```

Comment: This is especially unusual given that, [with a basic Index, `loc` will return all instances of the label if you have duplicates.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45636490/7954504)

Comment: FYI: If you initiate the index with `np.array` as `dtype=int` it still has problems so it is not an issue with floating points

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: The latest: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v0.20.3 (upvoted you for a cool name)

Comment: I think this might fall under the category of a bug, I've submitted a github issue at: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17464

Comment: CONCLUSION (per link above):  your directly constructing the MultiIndex is violating guarantees, namely that the levels are each unique. We don't explicitly check this as the public constructors guarantee this. To clarify, you certainly can have a non-unique MultiIndex (though generally discouraged as they are not that performant), but you would have duplicate labels, never level values.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.xs`

```
df.xs((0,1), level=[0,1])
Out[74]: 
           col0      col1  col2
idx0 idx1                      
0    1      9.0  example3  27.0
     1     16.0  example4  64.0
```

Using `.loc`

```
df.loc[0].loc[1]
Out[75]: 
      col0      col1  col2
idx1                      
1      9.0  example3  27.0
1     16.0  example4  64.0
```

Add `[]` in your secondary index: (PS: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers))

```
df.loc[(0, [1]),:]

Out[90]: 
           col0      col1  col2
idx0 idx1                      
0    1      9.0  example3  27.0
     1     16.0  example4  64.0
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question really ... I'm have a workaround, I'm asking why `.loc[[(0,1)]]` doesn't work. I kindly thank you for your further example, though this seems to just emphasise the unexpected behavior of `.loc[[(0,1)]]`!

Comment: can you explain why the `[1]` is necessary? It seems quite arbitrary !

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Check the link http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers

Comment: The docs still don't show an example of why `[1]` should behave differently to `1`. Fundamentally, when doing `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 1], :]` I get all the duplicates but `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[0, 1], :]` will only return one row. This is actually a really good example so I'll add to OP

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your multi-index is created correctly.

```
df = df.assign(
    idx0=[0] * 4 + [1] * 4, 
    idx1=[0, 0, 1, 1] * 2).set_index(['idx0', 'idx1'])
```

Using one of the correct ways to use `loc` for accessing the data:

```
>>> df.loc[(0, 1), :]
           col0      col1  col2
idx0 idx1                      
0    1        9  example3    27
     1       16  example4    64
```

Using the same command on the original dataframe, I get:
`TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index`.

**UPDATE**

As I mentioned before, you do not appear to be creating your multi-index correctly.  This dataframe with the properly constructed multi-index works as expected with your examples (using an older pandas, v 0.17.2).

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]], names=['idx0', 'idx1'])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [i**2/float(j), 'example{}'.format(i), i**3/float(j)]
        for j in range(1, len(idx0) + 1)
        for i in range(1, len(idx1) + 1)
    ],
    columns=['col0', 'col1', 'col2'],
    index=midx)
```

Using `midx` as defined above:

```
>>> midx
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]],
           names=[u'idx0', u'idx1'])
```

Using `midx` per your definition:

```
>>> midx
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]],
           names=[u'idx0', u'idx1'])
```

Comment: The `df` in the question has two `int64` indices, seems like it is created "properly".  Can you explain why this behaves as expected with your modification?

Comment: yes I came across the same. I'll make my `MultiIndex` creation cleaner in the example at the bottom. I compacted it to make my post shorter but I have the same confusion as @BradSolomon

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is this issue a case of there being duplicate values in the `levels` kwarg? It seems that perhaps the Pandas lib should throw an error if `levels` can't take duplicates?

Comment: Although ill advised, a dataframe can have identical column names.  So I believe `levels` should be able to accept duplicates for consistency.