# What causes "indexing past lexsort depth" warning in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm indexing a large multi-index Pandas df using `df.loc[(key1, key2)]`. Sometimes I get a series back (as expected), but other times I get a dataframe. I'm trying to isolate the cases which cause the latter, but so far all I can see is that it's correlated with getting a `PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance` warning.

I'd like to reproduce it to post here, but I can't generate another case that gives me the same warning. Here's my attempt:

```
def random_dates(start, end, n=10):
    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9
    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(3255000).reshape(465000,7))  # same shape as my data
df['date'] = random_dates(pd.to_datetime('1990-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01'), 465000)
df = df.set_index([0, 'date'])
df = df.sort_values(by=[3])  # unsort indices, just in case
df.index.lexsort_depth
> 0
df.index.is_monotonic
> False
df.loc[(0.9987185534991936, pd.to_datetime('2012-04-16 07:04:34'))]
# no warning
```

So my question is: **what causes this warning**? How do I artificially induce it?

Comment: Have you read: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex just checking

Comment: Yes - I was trying to unsort by index, so i sorted by a column

Comment: Either way it's clear that the index isn't sorted - the numbers are randomly generated.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

#### TL;DR: your index is unsorted and this severely impacts performance.

Sort your DataFrame's index using [`df.sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to address the warning and improve performance.

---

I've actually written about this in detail in my writeup: [Select rows in pandas MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927460/select-rows-in-pandas-multiindex-dataframe) (under "Question 3").

To reproduce,

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    list('aaaabbbbbccddddd'),
    list('tuvwtuvwtuvwtuvw')
], names=['one', 'two'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.arange(len(mux))}, mux)

         col
one two     
a   t      0
    u      1
    v      2
    w      3
b   t      4
    u      5
    v      6
    w      7
    t      8
c   u      9
    v     10
d   w     11
    t     12
    u     13
    v     14
    w     15
```

You'll notice that the second level is not properly sorted.

Now, try to index a specific cross section:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[('c', 'u')]]
PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
  # encoding: utf-8

         col
one two     
c   u      9
```

You'll see the same behaviour with `xs`:

```
df.xs(('c', 'u'), axis=0)
PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
  self.interact()

         col
one two     
c   u      9
```

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex), backed by [this timing test I once did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317984/4909087) seem to suggest that handling un-sorted indexes imposes a slowdown—Indexing is O(N) time when it could/should be O(1).

If you sort the index before slicing, you'll notice the difference:

```
df2 = df.sort_index()
df2.loc[pd.IndexSlice[('c', 'u')]]

         col
one two     
c   u      9


%timeit df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[('c', 'u')]]
%timeit df2.loc[pd.IndexSlice[('c', 'u')]]

802 µs ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
648 µs ± 20.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Finally, if you want to know whether the index is sorted or not, check with `MultiIndex.is_lexsorted`.

```
df.index.is_lexsorted()
# False

df2.index.is_lexsorted()
# True
```

---

As for your question on how to induce this behaviour, simply permuting the indices should suffice. This works if your index is unique:

```
df2 = df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(np.random.permutation(df2.index))]
```

If your index is not unique, add a `cumcount`ed level first,

```
df.set_index(
    df.groupby(level=list(range(len(df.index.levels)))).cumcount(), append=True) 
df2 = df.loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(np.random.permutation(df2.index))]
df2 = df2.reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
```

Comment: Superb answer (as always!) Only thing I'm still not quite sure about is under what conditions `loc`ing one row would return a series rather than a df (which was what originally led me to this). With my data, loc returns a series, but always returns a df using your examples.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Aha, I figured it out. The problem is that `df` has duplicate index entries! Try this: `df[~df.index.duplicated()].loc[('c', 'u')]`. Hope that explains it. If the index contains duplicate entries, the default behaviour is to return a DataFrame with all rows matching that index value. If only one row matches it, the result will be a DataFrame with a single row.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct! Definitely bounty-worthy :)

Comment: @JoshFriedlander thanks! Tiny thing though, it would've been better to wait out the 6 days for the bounty period before awarding it. In that time both the question and the answers are usually seen by a lot of folks and upvoted. ;)

Comment: ah, that's annoying...I'll know for next time

Comment: I was having poor performance with a multiindexed ~30M rows df. After the index sorting the performance boost has been dramatic. Thank you!

Comment: I have found that the most common reason for this error (when everything else is specified correctly) is having duplicated entries in the index. I wish pandas would specify this as the problem instead of the vague current error message that could apply to so many different issues.

Answer (score 5):

According to [pandas advanced indexing (Sorting a Multiindex)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex)

> On higher dimensional objects, you can sort any of the other axes by level if they have a MultiIndex

And also:

> Indexing will work even if the data are not sorted, but will be rather inefficient **(and show a PerformanceWarning)**. It will also return a copy of the data rather than a view:

According to them, you may need to ensure that indices are sorted properly.

Answer (score 1):

Series vs. dataframe output:
I also had the same problem that sometimes the output of `df.loc[(index1, index2)]` was a series and sometimes a dataframe. I found that this was caused by duplicated indices. If the dataframe had some duplicated indices, the output of `df.loc[(index1, index2)]` is a dataframe otherwise a series.

Comment: Yes, @cs95 said this to me in the comments below their answer

Answer (score 0):

On my case, PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance is for duplicate index on df.

Case:
Trying to read a excel file with pandas in a loop for each sheetname

In the sheet with duplicate index gives: PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance