# comparing two list of lists with a dataframe column python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I want to compare two list of lists with a dataframe column.

`list1=[[r2,r4,r6],[r6,r7]]`
`list2=[[p4,p5,p8],[p86,p21,p0,p94]]`

**Dataset:**

| rid | pid | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| r2 | p0 | banana |
| r2 | p4 | chocolate |
| r4 | p89 | apple |
| r6 | p5 | milk |
| r7 | p0 | bread |

**Output:**

`[[chocolate,milk],[bread]]`
As `r2` and `p4` occur in the `list1[0]`, `list2[0]` and in the **same row** in dataset, so `chocolate` must be stored. Similarly `r6` and `p5` occur in both lists at same position and in the same row in dataset,`milk` must be stored.

Comment: Why are `chocolate` and `milk` in the same list of your result

Comment: because r2,p4 and r6,p5 occur in list1[0] and list2[0] so, it appears in result[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

```py
result = []
for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
    res = df.loc[df["rid"].isin(l1) & df["pid"].isin(l2)]["value"].tolist()
    result.append(res)
```

```
[['chocolate', 'milk'], ['bread']]
```

### Explain

- `zip` will combine the two lists, equivalent to

```py
for i in range(len(list1)):
    l1 = list1[i]
    l2 = list2[i]
```

- `df["rid"].isin(l1) & df["pid"].isin(l2)` will combine the condition with `and operator` `&`

### Attation

- The length of list1 and list2 must be equal, otherwise, `zip` will ignore the rest element of the longer list.

Comment: Won't zip truncate the length of the longer list? Both the lists differ in length

Comment: @rk6t7, yes, but, as you say `because r2,p4 and r6,p5 occur in list1[0] and list2[0]`, so, there is no need to consider the rest part, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
from itertools import product

df = pd.DataFrame({'rid': {0: 'r2', 1: 'r2', 2: 'r4', 3: 'r6', 4: 'r7'},
 'pid': {0: 'p0', 1: 'p4', 2: 'p89', 3: 'p5', 4: 'p0'},
 'value': {0: 'banana', 1: 'chocolate', 2: 'apple', 3: 'milk', 4: 'bread'}})
list1 = [['r2','r4','r6'],['r6','r7']]
list2 = [['p4','p5','p8'],['p86','p21','p0','p94']]

# Generate all possible associations.
associations = (product(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2))

# Index for speed and convenience of the lookup.
df = df.set_index(['rid', 'pid']).sort_index()

output = [[df.loc[assoc, 'value'] for assoc in assoc_list if assoc in df.index] 
          for assoc_list in associations]

print(output)
```

```
[['chocolate', 'milk'], ['bread']]
```

Comment: I get the following error:PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.

Comment: @rk6t7 check my edit (I added `.sort_index()` after `df.set_index(['rid', 'pid'])`). ([Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520922/2246849))