# Is there anyway to avoid the lexsort warning without sorting the columns of a MultiIndexed DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand that there is some [performance rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307300/what-causes-indexing-past-lexsort-depth-warning-in-pandas) for sorting the columns (or indices) in a MultiIndexed pandas DataFrame. However, I have my own "user-interface" reasons for choosing the particular order of the columns. Is there any way to avoid the following warning without having to change the order of the columns?

```
PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
```

If it's impossible to do in a clean way, is there at least some way to temporarily sort the columns and then re-arrange their order back to what it was before the operation?

Here is some self-contained code:

```
import pandas as pd

N = 3
rangeN = list(range(1, N + 1))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [rangeN, rangeN], names=["level1", "level2"]
)
columns = [
    (
        "col_B",
        "col_B.1",
    ),
    (
        "col_B",
        "col_B.2",
    ),
]
components = range(1, 3)
columns += [("col_A", "col_A.1", f"col_A.1.{c}") for c in components]
columns += [("col_A", "col_A.2", f"col_A.2.{c}") for c in components]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=index)

df.loc[:, ("col_B", "col_B.2",)] = 7  # Warning thrown here

print(df)
```

which returns

```
                col_B             col_A                              
              col_B.1 col_B.2   col_A.1             col_A.2          
                  NaN     NaN col_A.1.1 col_A.1.2 col_A.2.1 col_A.2.2
level1 level2                                                        
1      1          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       2          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       3          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2      1          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       2          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       3          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3      1          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       2          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       3          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
c:\users\tfovid\draft.py:31: PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
  df.loc[:, ("col_B", "col_B.2",)] = 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have 3 levels in the column index, so add `slice(None)` to `.loc` helps:

```
df.loc[:, ("col_B", "col_B.2", slice(None))] = 7
print(df)
```

Prints without warning:

```
                col_B             col_A                              
              col_B.1 col_B.2   col_A.1             col_A.2          
                  NaN     NaN col_A.1.1 col_A.1.2 col_A.2.1 col_A.2.2
level1 level2                                                        
1      1          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       2          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       3          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2      1          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       2          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       3          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3      1          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       2          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
       3          NaN       7       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! However, (1) I'm not sure what adding `slice(None)` does, and (2) if this only works because there was a `None` level there to begin with?

Comment: @Tfovid `slice(None)` is used as *wildcard* It uses all content on that level (in this case level 3). If doesn't depend if the column name is `NaN` or something else. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers