# Pandas Business Day Offset: Request for Simple Example

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a dataframe, "df", with a datetime index. Here is a rough snapshot of its dimensions:

```
            V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1/12/2008   4   15  11  7   1
1/13/2008   5   2   8   7   1
1/14/2008   13  13  9   6   4
1/15/2008   14  15  12  9   3
1/16/2008   1   10  2   12  15
1/17/2008   10  5   9   9   1
1/18/2008   13  11  5   7   2
1/19/2008   2   6   7   9   6
1/20/2008   5   4   14  3   7
1/21/2008   11  11  4   7   15
1/22/2008   9   4   15  10  3
1/23/2008   2   13  13  10  3
1/24/2008   12  15  14  12  8
1/25/2008   1   4   2   6   15
```

Some of the days in the index are weekends and holidays.

I would like to move all dates, in the datetime index of "df", to their respective closest (US) business day (i.e. Mon-Friday, excluding holidays).

How would you recommend for me to do this? I am aware that Pandas has a ["timeseries offset"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html) facility for this. But, I haven't been able to find an example that walks a novice reader through this.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with this class but after looking at the source code it seems fairly straightforward to achieve this. Keep in mind that it picks the *next* closest business day meaning Saturday turns into Monday as opposed to Friday. Also making your index be non-unique will [decrease performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626058/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-non-unique-indexes-in-pandas) on your DataFrame, so I suggest assigning these values to a new column.

The one prerequisite is you have to make sure your index is any of these three types, [datetime](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.1/pandas/tseries/offsets.py#L1064), [timedelta, pd.tseries.offsets.Tick](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.1/pandas/tseries/offsets.py#L1079).

```
offset = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(n=0)

df.assign(
    closest_business_day=df.index.to_series().apply(offset)
)

            V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 closest_business_day
2008-01-12   4  15  11   7   1           2008-01-14
2008-01-13   5   2   8   7   1           2008-01-14
2008-01-14  13  13   9   6   4           2008-01-14
2008-01-15  14  15  12   9   3           2008-01-15
2008-01-16   1  10   2  12  15           2008-01-16
2008-01-17  10   5   9   9   1           2008-01-17
2008-01-18  13  11   5   7   2           2008-01-18
2008-01-19   2   6   7   9   6           2008-01-21
2008-01-20   5   4  14   3   7           2008-01-21
2008-01-21  11  11   4   7  15           2008-01-21
2008-01-22   9   4  15  10   3           2008-01-22
2008-01-23   2  13  13  10   3           2008-01-23
2008-01-24  12  15  14  12   8           2008-01-24
2008-01-25   1   4   2   6  15           2008-01-25
```