# How to multiply dataframe rows by an array based on an 'attribute' of the row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a big pandas dataframe DF which takes up nearly all my RAM.
Its index is always one of the following: 'c1','c2','c3'.

```
    0   1   2  ...  n
i            
c1  1   8  15
c2  2   9  16
c1  3  10  17
c3  4  11  18
c2  5  12  19
c1  6  13  20
c3  7  14  21
...
```

I also have a dictionary in which the keys 'match' the dataframe index labels. The values are lists/arrays with length n (equal to number of dataframe columns).

```
d = {'c1':[10,10,10,...],'c2':[100,100,100,...],'c3':[1000,1000,1000,...]}

len(d[<allkeys>]) == n >>> True
```

What I want to do is a simple dataframe multiplication based on an 'attribute' of the row -- in this case it's its index, but it could be a value from a column.
The result would look like this:

```
       0      1      2
i                     
c1    10     80    150
c2   200    900   1600
c1    30    100    170
c3  4000  11000  18000
c2   500   1200   1900
c1    60    130    200
c3  7000  14000  21000
```

I don't want to build a second dataframe DF2 in a way that I could just do DF*DF2, because I don't have enough RAM and because such dataframe seems pointless to me, meaning that it would just be a repetition of arrays/lists (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I thought about having a second dataframe like this:

```
       0     1     2
c1    10    10    10
c2   100   100   100
c3  1000  1000  1000
```

But when I do DF * DF2, somehow the index gets sorted and I don't know how this can be avoided.
Result:

```
          0         1         2
c1      100       800      1500
c1      300      1000      1700
c1      600      1300      2000
c2    20000     90000    160000
c2    50000    120000    190000
c3  4000000  11000000  18000000
c3  7000000  14000000  21000000
```

If you think there's another way to approach this problem (different data structures,libraries,etc) that would also be appreciated.

Code for samples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],1: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 2: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]}, index=pd.Index(['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c3', 'c2', 'c1', 'c3'], dtype='object', name='i'))
d = {'c1':[10,10,10],'c2':[100,100,100],'c3':[1000,1000,1000]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')
```

Comment: I would just have 2 remarks: *I have a big pandas dataframe DF which takes up nearly all my RAM*: bad idea because pandas need memory for its operation. *Its index is always one of the following: 'c1','c2','c3'*: bad idea because not unique indexes is generally the start point for later nightmares.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The reasoning behind the non unique indexes was that it would allow me to do the operation I was looking for. Thanks for pointing that out though -- I did a quick search and it appears do have some performance implications https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626058/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-non-unique-indexes-in-pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is deduplicate index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), multiple by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) by first level and last remove second level by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(np.arange(len(df)), append=True)
         .mul(df2, level=0)
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
print (df1)
       0      1      2
i                     
c1    10     80    150
c2   200    900   1600
c1    30    100    170
c3  4000  11000  18000
c2   500   1200   1900
c1    60    130    200
c3  7000  14000  21000
```

Answer (score 1):

As an old dinosaur that had to work on systems where memory was scarse, I would do what we used to do when loading everything in memory was not an option: I would just process the dataframe in chunks, saving to disk what is not required to be in live memory.

So I would:

- save the large dataframe to a csv file on disk and purge it from memory
- open that csv file to read it by chunks
- open a new csv file to save the resul (with an empty copy of the dataframe)
- then chunk by chunk:

  - read a chunk
  - process it
  - append it the the new csv file

Certainly not as efficient as buying more memory but robust and scalable.