# Do any libraries other than pandas use a MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas

Are there any libraries with data tables that allow you to define multiple levels of column names the way you can in pandas with [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html)?

It seems like there is no equivalent in [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944281/r-multi-index-on-columns-and-or-rows), [Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67088072/multi-level-indexing-of-data-frames-in-julia), [dask](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1493), [polars](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html#polars-does-not-have-a-multi-indexindex), etc. Is pandas the only package that does this?

For example this table below has 2 levels of column headers, which doesn't seem possible to directly represent in most other packages and would have to be unstacked.

[image]

Comment: Databases typically have composite indexes, which are the same thing.

Comment: In pandas MultiIndex can be used to represent multiple levels of keys both on the rows and the columns. I think SQL composite indexes are similar to a pandas MultiIndex on rows but doesn't apply for columns and am still curious about equivalents for that. I edited my post with an example if it's not clear what I mean

Comment: Because you can essentially stack a multilevel-column into a multilevel-index data, so most other libraries don't implement that?