# High-dimensional data structure in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, machine-learning, multi-index

What is best way to store and analyze high-dimensional date in python? I like Pandas DataFrame and Panel where I can easily manipulate the axis. Now I have a hyper-cube (dim >=4) of data. I have been thinking of stuffs like dict of Panels, tuple as panel entries. I wonder if there is a high-dim panel thing in Python.

update 20/05/16: 
Thanks very much for all the answers. I have tried MultiIndex and xArray, however I am not able to comment on any of them. In my problem I will try to use ndarray instead as I found the label is not essential and I can save it separately.

update 16/09/16:
I came up to use MultiIndex in the end. The ways to manipulate it are pretty tricky at first, but I kind of get used to it now.

Comment: `np.ndarray` is an underlying type for pandas DataFrame, but it supports more than two dimensions: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

Comment: Since Pandas has greatly improved MultiIndexing, this is generally favored instead of Panels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MultiIndex` is most useful for higher dimensional data as explained [in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226029/benefits-of-pandas-multiindex) because it allows you to work with any number of dimension in a `DataFrame` environment.

In addition to the `Panel`, there is also [Panel4D](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel4d-experimental) - currently in experimental stage. Given the advantages of `MultiIndex` I wouldn't recommend using either this or the three dimensional version. I don't think these data structures have gained much traction in comparison, and will indeed be phased out.

Comment: Panels and multi-dimensional panels are being deprecated in future versions in favour of `xarray`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#to-xarray

Answer (score 3):

If you need labelled arrays and pandas-like smart indexing, you can use `xarray` package which is essentially an n-dimensional extension of pandas Panel (panels are being deprecated in pandas in future in favour of xarray).

Otherwise, it may sometimes be reasonable to use plain numpy arrays which can be of any dimensionality; you can also have arbitrarily nested numpy record arrays of any dimension.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend continuing to use `DataFrame` but utilize the `MultiIndex` feature.  `DataFrame` is better supported and you preserve all of your dimensionality with the `MultiIndex`.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'], index=['A', 'B'])

df3 = pd.concat([df for _ in [0, 1]], keys=['one', 'two'])

df4 = pd.concat([df3 for _ in [0, 1]], axis=1, keys=['One', 'Two'])

print df4
```

Looks like:

```
      One    Two   
        a  b   a  b
one A   1  2   1  2
    B   3  4   3  4
two A   1  2   1  2
    B   3  4   3  4
```

This is a hyper-cube of data.  And you'll be much better served with support and questions and less bugs and many other benefits.