# python replacement for fortran 'type' record

Tags: python, data-structures, types, fortran, records

I have some fortran code that I would like to convert to python. Said code makes extensive use of a 'type' data structure to describe data files that have long headers containing multiple variables, as well as sub-headers, and the actual data itself which is stored in a five dimensional array; the useable dimensions of the array being defined by other variables in the header. In fortran I use an include file to define the type in each of the suite of programs I use.

In the below I've called the type 'SEQUENCE':

```
  TYPE SEQUENCE
    INTEGER NHEADER ! Number of items recorded from file header
    CHARACTER*(256) FILE
    CHARACTER*(8) UTC
    CHARACTER*(10) UTDATE
    CHARACTER*(24) OBJ_NAME
    CHARACTER*(24) OBJ_CLASS
    DOUBLE PRECISION MOD_TEMP
    DOUBLE PRECISION MOD_FREQ
    CHARACTER*(1) PMT
    CHARACTER*(6) MOD
    INTEGER FILNUM
    CHARACTER*(24) FILTER
    DOUBLE PRECISION MOD_AMP
    INTEGER HT1
    INTEGER GAIN1
    INTEGER HT2
    INTEGER GAIN2
    DOUBLE PRECISION WP_DELTA
    DOUBLE PRECISION WPA
    DOUBLE PRECISION WPB
    CHARACTER*(MAX_WP) WPSEQ
    DOUBLE PRECISION ROTA
    DOUBLE PRECISION ROTB
    CHARACTER*(MAX_ROT) ROTSEQ
    DOUBLE PRECISION TELESCOPE_PA
    CHARACTER*(7) WAVEFORM
    CHARACTER*(256) SKY_SUB
    CHARACTER*(256) OS_SUB1
    CHARACTER*(256) OS_SUB2
    CHARACTER*(256) NOTES
    INTEGER REPEATS
    INTEGER WP_ROTATIONS
    INTEGER ROTATIONS
    INTEGER INTEGRATIONS
    INTEGER CHANNELS
    INTEGER POINTS
    DOUBLE PRECISION ROT_POS(MAX_ROT)
    DOUBLE PRECISION PRG_MOD_TEMP(MAX_REP,MAX_ROT,MAX_INT)
    CHARACTER*(8) PRG_UTC(MAX_REP,MAX_ROT,MAX_INT)
    DOUBLE PRECISION DAT(MAX_REP,MAX_ROT,MAX_INT,N_CH,MAX_PT)
    DOUBLE PRECISION EXP_TIME
    DOUBLE PRECISION INT_TIME
    DOUBLE PRECISION TOTAL_SEQ_TIME
  END TYPE
```

In case your wondering these files represent data attained by an instrument that goes through a number of configurations for each data block. Some of the configurations are nominally equivalent others are measuring an opposite state of the system.

As you can see there are a number of different data types in the structure, and times are currently being stored as strings, which is not ideal. Operations involving time are a total pain in fortran, being able to more easily deal with this in python is one of the motivations for switching.

In some of the programs I make arrays of multiple SEQUENCEs. In others I need to perform mathematical operations along particular combinations of the dimensions in SEQUENCE.DAT(). Being fortran this is typically done with lots of loops and if statements.

I'm moderately new to python, so before I rewrite a lot of code I need to figure out what the best way to do this is. Or else do it again in a year.

Initially I hoped that pandas would provide the answer, but it seems you can't create panels of more than 3 dimensions, and the dataframes have to be all the same size. I don't really want to have to create my own classes from scratch as this seems like a lot of work to build functionality that might be more easily attained in another way. Should I be using records? Or something else?

What would you recommend? What advantages are there in terms of simplicity/ease of getting started and/or functionality?

Comment: Naming a non-sequence type `SEQUENCE` is a bit... strange or even misleading.

Comment: It really depends what exactly you are wanting to do. Do you require binary compatibility? Will you read it from files written in Fortran? Why can't you just create a class with the exact same fields?

Comment: *"Operations involving time are a total pain in fortran, being able to more easily deal with this in python is one of the motivations for switching."* Have you tried to use some library? https://github.com/wavebitscientific/datetime-fortran

Comment: perhaps relevant https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: and also http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311699/high-dimensional-data-structure-in-python

Comment: It's named a sequence because the data block is called a sequence in the literature. The original code is written in Fortran77, and whilst I guess I could deal with date and time better in fortran, it seems like a lot of hassle, and it's not the only reason for switching. There are other python packages I would like to make use of.