# Changing a cell value based on other rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `Result` that comes from a SQL query:

```
Loc  ID   Bank
1    23   NULL
1    24   NULL
1    25   NULL
2    23   6
2    24   7
2    25   8
```

I am trying to set the values of `Loc == 1` Bank equal to the Bank of `Loc == 2` when the `ID` is the same, resulting in:

```
Loc  ID   Bank
1    23   6
1    24   7
1    25   8
2    23   6
2    24   7
2    25   8
```

Here is where I am at with the code, I know the ending is super simple I just can't wrap my head around a solution that doesn't involve iterating over every row (9000~).

`result.loc[(result['Loc'] == '1'), 'bank'] = ???`

Comment: Answers all assume that your `Loc` values are integer, which you don't. Do we have to take care of this ?

Comment: `Loc` is actually a string in the real dataframe, this is a very simplified version in the post

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fillna()` and `transform()`

```
df.fillna({'Bank':df.groupby('ID')['Bank'].transform('first')})
```

Original Answer:

You can try this. It uses `map()` to get the values from ID.

```
for_map = df.loc[df['Loc'] == 2].set_index('ID')['Bank'].squeeze().to_dict()
df.loc[df['Loc'] == 1,'Bank'] = df.loc[df['Loc'] == 1,'Bank'].fillna(df['ID'].map(for_map))
```

Output:

```
   Loc  ID  Bank
0    1  23   6.0
1    1  24   7.0
2    1  25   8.0
3    2  23   6.0
4    2  24   7.0
5    2  25   8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

[Why not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226029/benefits-of-pandas-multiindex) use [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) ?

*Commonalities*

```
# Arguments,
_0th_level = 'Loc'
merge_key  = 'ID'
value_key  = 'Bank'  # or a list of colnames or `slice(None)` to propagate all columns values.
src_key    = '2'
dst_key    = '1'
# Computed once for all,
df         = result.set_index([_0th_level, merge_key])
df2        = df.xs(key=src_key, level=_0th_level, drop_level=False)
df1_       = df2.rename(level=_0th_level, index={src_key: dst_key})
```

---

***First (naive) approach***

```
df.loc[df1_.index, value_key] = df1_
# to get `result` back : df.reset_index()
```

---

***Second (robust) approach***

That being shown, the first approach may be [illegal](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike) (since pandas version 1.0.0) if there is one or more missing label [...].

So if you must ensure that indexes exist both at source and destination, the following does the job on shared `ID`s only.

```
df1 = df.xs(key=dst_key, level=_0th_level, drop_level=False)
idx = df1.index.intersection(df1_.index)  # <-----
df.loc[idx, value_key] = df1_.loc[idx, value_key]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a self merge on the dataframe, on `ID`, then filter for rows where it is equal to 2:

```
(
    df.merge(df, on="ID")
    .loc[lambda df: df.Loc_y == 2, ["Loc_x", "ID", "Bank_y"]]
    .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split("_")[0] if "_" in x else x)
    .astype({"Bank": "Int8"})
    .sort_values("Loc", ignore_index=True)
)

     Loc    ID  Bank
0     1     23  6
1     1     24  7
2     1     25  8
3     2     23  6
4     2     24  7
5     2     25  8
```

You could also stack/unstack, although this fails if you have duplicate indices:

```
(
    df.set_index(["Loc", "ID"])
    .unstack("Loc")
    .bfill(1)
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .reindex(columns=df.columns)
)

    Loc     ID  Bank
0     1     23  6.0
1     2     23  6.0
2     1     24  7.0
3     2     24  7.0
4     1     25  8.0
5     2     25  8.0
```